# How to reduce margin between two React-Native-Elements - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm stuck on how to reduce the distance between my two react native elements the UI looks as follows for now.

[image]

I want the distance between the Email and password Field to be a little bit smaller.

**Also I don't want the logo to be hidden when the keyboard popup**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "reduce the distance between my two react native elements"? Do you want to decrease the `margin` or `padding` between the elements?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is huge margin between Email and Password Field. How can i reduce that.

Comment: You should pass a style object containing the desired margin and padding to the `containerStyle` prop of the input(s).

Comment: I did that it didn't work

Comment: My guess is this is a limitation of [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements).

As a workaround, did you try setting a negative margin?

Comment: Overriding the `minHeight` might also be a solution.

Comment: Showing at least _some_ code would definitely help.